# Sometimes Region can't build right region

Tags: bugs, finite-element-method, regions, mesh

During my work with NDSolveFEM I found strange behavior of function **Region**.

```
a = 600;
reg1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {6 a, a}];
hole1 = Disk[{3 a, 0.75 a}, a/8];
hole2 = Disk[{3 a, 0.25 a}, a/8];
hole3 = Disk[{2.5 a, 0.5 a}, a/8];
resreg = RegionDifference[reg1, RegionUnion[hole1, hole2, hole3]]
```

So, it is really simple region with 3 holes near the centre of rectangle 6a * a.

*resreg* is:

```
BooleanRegion[#1 && ! (#2 || #3 || #4) &, {Rectangle[{0, 0}, 
{3600, 600}], Disk[{1800, 450.}, 75], Disk[{1800, 150.}, 75], Disk[{1500., 300.}, 75]}]
```

If I try to plot it by **Region** on my first computer, I will receive the simple Quad region 1 * 1:
[image]

So, this region is unmeshable and I can't understand the reason of this behavior.

If I try it on my notebook. I will receive the right plot and meshable region.
[image]

Mesh of region:
[image]

Both computers have Windows 10 with Mathematica v 11.3. How I can make **Region** plot right image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug and you should report it to support@wolfram.com. Here is why - simply because `DiscretizeRegion` has the same problem and does not give a message about it:

```
a = 600;
reg1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {6 a, a}];
hole1 = Disk[{3 a, 0.75 a}, a/8];
hole2 = Disk[{3 a, 0.25 a}, a/8];
hole3 = Disk[{2.5 a, 0.5 a}, a/8];
resreg = RegionDifference[reg1, RegionUnion[hole1, hole2, hole3]];
```

[image]

The finite element functions have the same problem, but they give a message about what is going on. Start with a fresh kernel:

```
Quit
```

And then:

```
a = 600;
reg1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {6 a, a}];
hole1 = Disk[{3 a, 0.75 a}, a/8];
hole2 = Disk[{3 a, 0.25 a}, a/8];
hole3 = Disk[{2.5 a, 0.5 a}, a/8];
resreg = RegionDifference[reg1, RegionUnion[hole1, hole2, hole3]];
NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh[resreg]
```

This gives a message:

[image]

So now we know that the `RegionBounds` computation either timed out or was not able to compute the bounds. However, when you call

```
RegionBounds[resreg]
```

You will get the bounds. Once the bounds are computed they are cached. That's why we needed the `Quit` above to make sure that we start from the same state.

As a workaround you can compute the `RegionBounds` before calling `Region`, or, if you happen to already have a FEM mesh just use:

```
 Region[MeshRegion[myFEMMesh]]
```

or

```
MeshRegion[myFEMMesh]
```

Answer (score 4):

If `Region` cannot do it alone, you try `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` with the option `MaxCellMeasure` to control the resolution of the discretization. In this case, it helps.

```
length = 0.5;
R = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[resreg, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> length}]
```

[image]

You can obtain a mesh with `DiscretizeRegion`:

```
S = DiscretizeRegion[R]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

```
a=600;q = ImplicitRegion[x >= 0 && x <= 6*a && y >= 0 && 
y <= a && (x - 3 a)^2 + (y - 3/4*a)^2 >= 
 a^2/64 && (x - 3 a)^2 + (y - 1/4*a)^2 >= 
 a^2/64 && (x - 5/2*a)^2 + (y - 1/2*a)^2 >= a^2/64, {x, y}];Region[q]
```

[image]