# Problems using DensityPlot when solving Laplace's equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve Laplace's equation in 2 dimensions with potencial boundary conditions at the edges of an external square and an internal circle.
Everything seems to work fine until the point where I try to obtain a DensityPlot to visualize the the obtained potential at all points. When I execute the density plot line, I am returned with a diagram that displays the solution of the equation for only a fraction of the region where I solved the equation. How can I fix this ?
The code is as follows:

```
α = 
 RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-50, -50}, {50, 50}], Disk[{0, 0}, 5]]
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 100, x^2 + y^2 == 25], 
   u[x, -50] == u[x, 50] == u[-50, y] == u[50, y] == 0}, 
  u, {x, y} ∈ α]

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ α, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: This is what I mean by "only a fraction of the region where I solved the equation is shown.]

Comment: I filed this as a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [bad day for `Region`s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/185539), I guess...

Until `NDSolve` will dicretize it correctly, you can discretize the region yourself:

```
α = DiscretizeRegion[
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-50, -50}, {50, 50}], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 5]],
   MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 1}
   ];
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 100, x^2 + y^2 == 25], 
    u[x, -50] == u[x, 50] == u[-50, y] == u[50, y] == 0}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ α];
DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ α, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Using `DiscretizeRegion` is not ideal for FEM based computations. See my answer for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your continuous edits of my lazily written posts!

Comment: Dito. That's my way of showing that I read them! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Using `DiscretizeRegion` is not the best solution. This is because `DiscretizeRegion` will only provide a linear approximation for a region. A better approximation is to use `ToElementMesh` which can generate a second order accurate approximation to the region:

```
α = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-50, -50}, {50, 50}], Disk[{0, 0}, 5]]
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 100, x^2 + y^2 == 25], 
   u[x, -50] == u[x, 50] == u[-50, y] == u[50, y] == 0}, 
  u, {x, y} ∈ α]
sol["ElementMesh"]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

DensityPlot understands `ElementMesh`:

```
DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ sol["ElementMesh"], 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Now to look at the approximation quality difference:

```
N[exact = Integrate[1, {x, y} ∈ α]]
9921.460183660256`

exact - Area[DiscretizeRegion[α]]
-2.610161994172813`

exact - Total[sol["ElementMesh"]["MeshElementMeasure"], 2]
-0.004173680044914363`
```

Clearly the use of an `ElementMesh` is superior here as it much better approximates the curved boundaries.

This is explained in more detail in the section [Comparing ElementMesh and MeshRegion in the Element Mesh Generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html).